# Registering email and password is not authorizing in Firebase Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to register a user with email and password in react js and firebase authorization.but my email and password is not authorizing and saving in firebase

Here is my Signup Page view

```
function  Signup() {
const {NewSignup}=UserContext();
const [email,setEmail]=useState("");
const [password,setPassword]=useState("");
const [error,setError]=useState("");
const handleSubmit=async()=>{
  try{
  await NewSignup(email,password);
  }catch(err){
    setError(err.message);
  }
    };
useEffect(()=>{
    if(error){
     swal(error);
    }
} ,[error]);
  return (
    <div className="Auth-form-container">
      <form className="Auth-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="Auth-form-content">
          <h3 className="Auth-form-title">Sign Up</h3>
          {/* {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>} */}
          <div className="form-group mt-3">
            <label>Email address</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              className="form-control mt-1"
              placeholder="Enter email"
              onChange={(e) =>setEmail(e.target.value)} 
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group mt-3">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              className="form-control mt-1"
              placeholder="Enter password"
              onChange={(e) =>setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
       
          <p className="forgot-password text-right mt-2">
          Already Have a Account ?  <a href="#">Login</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now this is my UserAuthContext page where i write functions for signup and login for user
I am doing this with ContextApi

```
export const UserAuthContext = createContext();
export const UserAuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const {user,setUser}=useState();
 function NewSignup(email,password){
    console.log("Auth",email,password);
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password);
    }
   
 const Login=(email,password)=>{
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password);
    }
// useEffect(() => {
//    const unsubscribe= onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentuser) => {
//         setUser(currentuser);
//     });
//     return () => {
//         unsubscribe();
//     }
// }, []);
    return (
        <UserAuthContext.Provider value={{user,NewSignup,Login}}>
        {children}
        </UserAuthContext.Provider>
    );
    }
export const UserContext =()=>{

    const {user,NewSignup,Login}=useContext(UserAuthContext);

    return {user,NewSignup,Login};
}
```

How to solve this issue? I have been stuck on it from past two days.

My App.js

```
 <Router>
     <Header/>
    
     <UserAuthContextProvider>
     <Routes>
         <Route exact path="/" element={<Login/>} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup/>} /> 
       </Routes>
       </UserAuthContextProvider>
       </Router>
```

Comment: Please don't Write your Questions with Random upper Case Letters. It's very Annoying to Read text Like this -- and you've clearly been doing that with your previous questions too, and other people have spent their time fixing it.

Comment: Sorry I will take care next time